# how to convert list of list of string to dictionary in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm doing a project where i need to convert a list<list> to a dictionary object i have used

`var myDic = GetSomeStrings().ToDictionary(x => x, x => x.Number('A'));`

to convert but it didn't work for list<list>

Comment: So there must be a key for each sublist. What would comprise such a key?

Comment: What's an example of the data structure you currently have and what are you expecting the resulting data structure to look like?  Did you just mean to do a `.SelectMany()` first to flatten your lists?

Comment: You want something like this??
Dictionary<string, item> stringItems = GetSomeStrings().SelectMany(b => b.items)
                                   .GroupBy(i => i.id)
                                   .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g.First());

Comment: i'm using a api and api i giving data in list<list<string>> form and i need to convert it to dictionary for searching purpose

Comment: the data is in {{"0","some data"},{"0","some data"} } form

Comment: Please, improve your question and provide sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `.ToDictionary(sublist => sublist[0], sublist => sublist[1])`

```
var list = new List<List<string>>()
{
    new List<string>() { "0", "A" },
    new List<string>() { "1", "B" }
};

var dictionary = list.ToDictionary(sublist => sublist[0], sublist => sublist[1]);

foreach (var (key, value) in dictionary)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{key}: {value}");
}
```